# SQL Select Data That Matches Condition, Display First, Then Sort Remaining Data

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

Just need some help with a SQL statement, I have a table that has a bunch of user data, currently I am getting all the data by rowid descending. However I need to modify the way the data is displayed as follows:

The table has a field in which users can specify their own value or the can choose the default value. When choosing the default value the field is auto populated with a "randomstring_standardefaultvalue".

So basically I need to select all the data in which the user did not choose the defaultvalue and have them order descending and then grab all the rows in which the user selected the defaultvalue and populate them after the first set of data sorted by descending rowid.

My current SQL Looks like this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userform ORDER BY _rowid_ DESC LIMIT {$offset}, {$pl};";
```

Table Data:

```
rowid  date  username  defaultoruniquevalue  member  etc...
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

ANSWER:

```
SELECT *, IF(defaultoruniquevalue LIKE CONCAT('%','defaultstring','%'), 1, 0) AS uses_default
FROM table
ORDER BY uses_default ASC, _rowid_ DESC
LIMIT {$offset}, {$pl
```

Comment: The biggest issue is that the stored data whether it is default or unique in the defaultoruniquevalue  row is appended with a random string. 


So we have a bunch of data as follows: randomstring_default randomstring_default randomstring_default randomstring_unique1 randomstring_unique2 randomstring_unique3 randomstring_unique4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly, but it sounds like you need to add a WHERE clause to your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM userform
WHERE defaultoruniquevalue != "default"
ORDER BY rowid DESC
LIMIT {$offset}, {$pl}
```

*Edit*

```
SELECT *, IF(defaultoruniquevalue LIKE '%_default', 1, 0) AS uses_default
FROM userform
ORDER BY uses_default ASC, rowid DESC
LIMIT {$offset}, {$pl}
```

Comment: Yup that's absolutely works, my only issue is with the default value, the issue is that the stored data whether it is default or unique is appended with a random string. So we have a bunch of data as follows:


randomstring_default
randomstring_default
randomstring_default
randomstring_unique1
randomstring_unique2
randomstring_unique3
randomstring_unique4

Comment: Are you able to tell apart the default and unique values? i.e. do you know the default value up front? If so, change the `WHERE` clause to: `WHERE defaultoruniquevalue LIKE '%_defaultvalue'`

Comment: This worked with the Like statement however the second part was that I still need to get all the rows with the unique data in the field to be return first and sorted desc by rowid.

Comment: Then what you need is a blend of all of the answers here. I've edited my post; now the query adds a new column that indicates whether the default value was used. Then it orders it by uniques first and defaults second, and then by rowid.

Comment: This one worked perfectly, modified the statement slightly to use CONCAT as @john-woo recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `CASE` in `order by` clause

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE..
ORDER BY (CASE defaultoruniquevalue
               WHEN 'randomstring_standardefaultvalue' THEN 0 
               ELSE 1 END) DESC,
         rowid DESC
```

Comment: is there any advantage of using `CASE .. WHEN .. THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` over plain comparison?

Comment: @mvds - Not in MySQL, but you can't put boolean expressions in a WHERE clause in some other RDBMS.  So, this pattern is much more portable.

Comment: With this statement, since the default value is also always prefixed with a unique can I replace the WHEN statement line with a LIKE %_defaultbg THEN 0

Comment: @SeanKumar yes you can, but you need to use `CONCAT`. ex, `CASE WHEN defaultoruniquevalue LIKE CONCAT('%','defaultbg','%')......` if you need pattern matching.